# How to make git to work with pagent(putty) on Windows?

Tags: ssh, git, putty

I'm using Windows x64 and I'm not able to make msysgit to work using pagent authentication.

Here are some details:

- Putty is working without pagent without any problems.
- I have only one key loaded in pagent
- SSH auth using putty to git@github.com works (not shell allowed)
- I tried [Putty 0.60 x86](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and [Putty 0.60 x64](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=251) and TortoisePlink - same results for all.
- the problem could be related to http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=251

The problem is that:

```
 plink -v -a -ssh git@github.com git version
 FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As silly at it may seam the reason for this problem is that `plink` will use the default hostname/ip from the *Default Settings* and will **ignore command line parameters**.

The solution is to remove hostname/ip from Default settings.

Also if you fail to connect due to fingerprint you should first connect one time using putty in order to store the fingerprint, just run `putty git@github.com`.

Comment: I don't have a ip or hostname set in PuTTY default settings but I still have this issue.

from win7, plink can't connect to my server boopsie by hostname - it's appending .home and going to a totally different ip:

> c:\me>plink -v me@boopsie
> Looking up host "boopsie.home"
> Connecting to 67.220.66.112 port 22

But command line works fine:

    c:\me>ping boopsie
    Pinging boopsie[192.168.1.2] with 32 bytes of data:
    Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64