# git clone times out even though ssh -T works fine?

Tags: git

I used to have a working Git installation on Windows, but for some reason, it's not working anymore, and I don't know what to do to fix it.

If I were to follow [GitHub's setup tutorial](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/), it says that all I'd need to do to verify things are copasetic is to type

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

and when I do that, things are dandy:

```
C:\
> ssh -T git@github.com
Hi klauern! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

So I feel confident that I can clone one of my projects locally (such as a fork of a project I have):

```
C:\
> git clone git@github.com:klauern/ruby.git
Cloning into 'ruby'...
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can get through to this using an `https://` protocol behind an HTTP proxy, but I should be able to go through the `ssh` protocol, too, right?

### Edit

I'll add that I am using the windows install of Git from http://git-scm.com/, I have PuTTy and PAgeant installed and working, as well as a `~/.ssh` folder with all the keys in it.  As I'd mentioned above, this *used to work*, but now it doesn't, and the only test I know is `ssh -T`.

Comment: This wouldn't help? http://superuser.com/questions/121304/how-to-make-git-to-work-with-pagentputty-on-windows, related to http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=251 (or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690317/cant-push-commits-to-central-repository)

Comment: Excellent.  That worked for me.  If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'd gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: Good to know. I have added an answer pointing to the plink issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "[How to make git to work with pagent(putty) on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/121304/how-to-make-git-to-work-with-pagentputty-on-windows)" mentions an issue with plink, related to [issue 251](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=251).

> This seams to be a bug in `putty`/`plink`: `plink` will just you the IP specified in `Default Settings` (`putty`) and ignore your command line hostname if you specify one.

The question "[Can't Push Commits to Central Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690317/cant-push-commits-to-central-repository)" also reminds us to check your origin declaration (`git remote show origin`)